# collection.fetch() does not yield me response

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
exports.definition = {

    config : {
        // table schema and adapter information
    },

    extendModel: function(Model) {      
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // Extend, override or implement the Backbone.Model methods                     
        });
        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

        }); // end extend

        return Collection;
    }
}
```

When i try to do `var model = Alloy.createCollection('model');`

```
alert(appointments.fetch());
```

I don't get any result.

Comment: fetch is asynchronous.you can use `appointments.fetch({success: function(model, response, options){console.log(model, response);}})`

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous. As so, it will return a promise, or you need to set up a callback:

```
appointments.fetch().done(function( r ) { console.log(r) });
```

Also, never use `alert` to debug; this is useless. Always open your console and use `console.log`

Comment: is `appointments` an instance of a Backbone collection or model? (e.g.: `console.log( appointments instanceOf Backbone.Model )`)

Comment: And you're using it on the server or in the browser? Did you change the `Backbnoe.Sync` method (or are you using a plugin changing the syncing behavior, like `backbone.localstorage`)?